# Spring boot restTemplate and Connection time out

Tags: java, http, spring-boot, tomcat

When I am invoking a rest service, I get the ResourceAccessException. I do not know why it occurs. Maybe because the service is down, but this happens intermittently. I want to know:

1. Why does it occur?
2. If I don't have defined any timeout (read or connection), the default
   value is -1 that is interpreted as undefined. So, what is default timeout?
3. Does Tomcat configure a default timeout?
4. How can i find this value?

In my traces, i see that the exception is thrown after 2min 7 secs, this timeout must be configured in some place, no?

I'm using java 8, spring boot 1.5.10 and my services client and server are deployed on a cloud server. I have configured the certificates in the server.

```
try {
        LOGGER.info("AuditLogDataMapper : doNetworkReqeustMessageAuditLog() :: sending....");
        restTemplate.postForLocation(auditLogServiceHost, request);
        LOGGER.info("AuthorizationApiBackend : Sent network message to Audit-log service");
        return true;
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        LOGGER.error("RestClientException in Audit-log Service", e);
    }
```

My exception:

```
2018/06/25 16:47:57,993 [INFO  ] (AuditLogRestClient.java:45) com.santander.ck.splitter.web.restclient.AuditLogRestClient : AuditLogDataMapper : doNetworkReqeustMessageAuditLog() :: sending.... 
2018/06/25 16:50:04,869 [ERROR ] (AuditLogRestClient.java:54) com.santander.ck.splitter.web.restclient.AuditLogRestClient : RestClientException in Audit-log Service
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://ck-da-audit-log-da-processing-dev.appls.cap2.paas.gsnetcloud.corp/audit-log/audit": Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:674) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForLocation(RestTemplate.java:363) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at com.santander.ck.splitter.web.restclient.AuditLogRestClient.doNetworkRequestMessageAuditLog(AuditLogRestClient.java:50) [classes!/:?]
at com.santander.ck.splitter.integration.AuthReportHandler.handle(AuthReportHandler.java:60) [classes!/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
```